# Run-time error '424': Object Required error when using ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a `Run-time error '424': Object Required` error with the code below.

```
Sub GetData()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `.Row` - This returns the row number not a reference to a cell

```
Sub GetData()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Sub
```